# RegEx for getting string inside parenthesis even if string itself contains parenthesises

Tags: regex, regex-group

If the title is not explainatory enough I will try to explain with actual examples.

If we have the examples:
`_(something)`
then the result would be
`something`

Next example:
`_(something (else))`
the result would be
`something (else)`

And the last example would be
`_(something) _(else) ${_(yes)}`
and the result would be
`something else yes`

I have the following regex atm: `/_\(([^)\\/]+)\)/g` but this regex does not include the last 
parenthesis in the second example so currently it becomes:
`something (else`

I would appreciate if someone have any fix for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're looking for is a way to match "nested" or "balanced" parentheses. Pure regular expressions aren't capable of this feat, although several implementations of them have been extended to be able to handle it; see the answers to any of the many other questions on the topic.

Comment: @MarkReed thanks for you comment. You led me in the right direction and I was able to find the solution to the issue. The solution is `_\(\s?(.+?\)?)\)`